# Nividia-396 installation blocked by libglx on 18.04

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, 18.04

I try to install the driver package nvidia-396 on my laptop as it is required to run cuda.

When I try to do it through apt I get a kind of error I never encountered before :

```
trying to replace " /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_indirect.so.0 ",which
belong to the package libglx-mesa0:amd64 18.0.0~rc5-1ubuntu1
errors have been encountered during the execution of : 
/var/cuda-repo-9-2-local/./nvidia-396_396.26-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

I've tried to remove the libglx-mesa0 package but it didn't change anything.

I run ubuntu 18.04. My GPU is a Nvidia Quadro K3100M.

Thank you very much for any help you could provide.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is bug in the package. Temporary solution is to force the installation by:

```
dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-396_396.26-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: If you're installing directly from PPA, you can use `apt install nvidia-396 -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite"`

Comment: Actually, OP is using Ubuntu 18.04, so it would be apt install nvidia-driver-396.

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu did recommend to me trying `apt install --fix-broken` to solve the issue I head with `libglx-mesa0` being installed by nvidia-410.

I couldn't figure which `.deb` is causing the issue exactly so I just passed `Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite"` to the suggested command:

```
sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" install --fix-broken
```