# how to address apt-upgrade problem involving libglx-mesa0 and Nvidia driver

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, mesa

I have an Nvidia 1070 system with Ubuntu 18.04, Nvidia driver 396.37, CUDA 9.0, and then TensorFlow and Keras running on it.

Having run `sudo apt update`, when I run `sudo apt upgrade`, I get the following:

```
$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libglx-mesa0 : Depends: libglapi-mesa (= 18.0.5-0ubuntu0~18.04.1) but 18.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.2 is installed
                Breaks: libglx-mesa0:i386 (!= 18.0.5-0ubuntu0~18.04.1) but 18.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.2 is installed
 libglx-mesa0:i386 : Breaks: libglx-mesa0 (!= 18.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.2) but 18.0.5-0ubuntu0~18.04.1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

When I attempt the suggested `sudo apt --fix-broken install` I see the following:

```
$ sudo apt --fix-broken installReading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libllvm6.0 libllvm6.0:i386 x11proto-dri2-dev x11proto-gl-dev
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libglx-mesa0
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libglx-mesa0
1 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 256 not to upgrade.
155 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/135 kB of archives.
After this operation, 9216 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 591832 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libglx-mesa0_18.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libglx-mesa0:amd64 (18.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.2) over (18.0.5-0ubuntu0~18.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libglx-mesa0_18.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_indirect.so.0', which is also in package nvidia-396 396.37-0ubuntu1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libglx-mesa0_18.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Based on my investigating this, I am prompted by [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1095400/654589) and [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-390/+bug/1753796/comments/8), to run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" install --fix-broken
```

However, I really would rather not screw up my setup (as it was a challenge getting compatible versions of CUDA, TensorFlow, Keras etc. working at all) so would value thoughts on whether this is a safe approach.

---

EDIT: Following [this suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1131195/how-to-address-apt-upgrade-problem-involving-libglx-mesa0-and-nvidia-driver?noredirect=1#comment1873901_1131195) by @Jos, I made a backup of `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_indirect.so.0` and the proceeded with the `--force-overwrite` approach. Following this, the infrastructure of TensorFlow, Keras and so on all seems to be working fine.

```
$ sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" install --fix-broken
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libllvm6.0 libllvm6.0:i386 x11proto-dri2-dev x11proto-gl-dev
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libglx-mesa0
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libglx-mesa0
1 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 256 not to upgrade.
155 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/135 kB of archives.
After this operation, 9216 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 591832 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libglx-mesa0_18.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libglx-mesa0:amd64 (18.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.2) over (18.0.5-0ubuntu0~18.04.1) ...
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
dpkg: warning: trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_indirect.so.0', which is also in package nvidia-396 396.37-0ubuntu1
```

Comment: You could make a backup of `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_indirect.so.0` first. The message is saying that the same file is provided by two packages, and you have the first one already installed. The `apt` process cannot know which of the two files you want installed. They may very well have the same contents. So backup the file, install with `--force-overwrite` and see if the error goes away.

Comment: @Jos Great, thanks for the suggestion, the `--force-overwrite` approach has apparently worked and the cautious backup of `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_indirect.so.0` was a good suggestion.

Comment: Had the same problem upgrading a system from 16.04 to 18.04, and the answer below worked.  I had nvidia-450 installed and the mesa stuff during the upgrade for some reason conflicted over that file.

Answer (score 11):

**TL;DR**

Beware, the solution below uses `--force-overwrite`, it'll come with caveats.

From @Jos comment:

```
sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" install --fix-broken
```

Nvidia drivers, CUDA and libglx packaging conflict on Ubuntu is always sooo messy -_-|||