# System Update broken by nvidia package

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, dpkg

Trying to update my Ubuntu system. Getting this error on some Nvidia driver. It broke the update and only prompting to `apt --fix-broken install` now. And that command is failing as well.

I couldn't find any solution to fix this broken update. Any suggestion to fix this ?

```
root@rajhome:~# apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libllvm7
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libglx-mesa0
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libglx-mesa0
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
91 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/142 kB of archives.
After this operation, 23.6 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 244787 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libglx-mesa0_19.0.2-1ubuntu1.1~18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libglx-mesa0:amd64 (19.0.2-1ubuntu1.1~18.04.1) over (18.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libglx-mesa0_19.0.2-1ubuntu1.1~18.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_indirect.so.0', which is also in package nvidia-418 418.67-0ubuntu1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libglx-mesa0_19.0.2-1ubuntu1.1~18.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: related: [how to address apt-upgrade problem involving libglx-mesa0 and Nvidia driver](https://askubuntu.com/q/1131195/3712)

Comment: @jfs Thanks. solved using the answer you linked.